# Usage of the word 'only'

Tags: grammar

Is the phrase 'only 4 japanese out of 8 people' grammatically correct?
Can 'only' be used like this?

Comment: It is not a complete sentence and Japanese are people too

Comment: Do you mean *4 out of 8 Japanese people* or do you mean *out of 8 people, 4 are Japanese* (or something else)?

Answer (score 1):

If the sentence means something like  "Out of 8 people {present there} only 4 Japanese {responded to the challenge}" then it is correct.

Comment: Please elaborate and give reasons for your answer to help OP make his decision.

Answer (score 0):

> Only 4 out of 8 Japanese people....

This is the correct form

Comment: ...unless the OP means to say '4 people are Japanese out of 8'.

Comment: It's fair, they must elaborate

Answer (score 0):

There are two concepts in play here — that it was 4 out of 8, and that all of the 4 were Japanese.  Further, you would use “only” only if 4 was surprisingly few.

Putting 2 and 2 together, one might infer that the point is that it was only Japanese people who responded.  If so, you should say that explicitly.